# crontab schedules and cron jobs

Tags: linux, centos, cron, scheduled-task

I've put two files in the `/etc/cron.d/` directory:

The first makes a new post everyday at 12:00AM:

```
0 0 * * * php /var/www/site1/helper post:make
```

The second updates the latest post every 10 minutes

```
10 * * * * php /var/www/site1/helper post:update
```

Do I have to do something else for this job to run based on the time (eg. every 10 minutes) or do I have to do `crontab job1` and `crontab job2`?

**EDIT**: I also installed cronie.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Putting files in cron.d is enough. However, your last entry should be:

```
*/10 * * * * php /var/www/site1/helper post:update
```

Otherwise it runs once an hour, at the 10th minute.

Comment: And as mentioned below, add a user. I didn't look closely enough and thought php was your user :)

Answer (score 5):

Also, add

```
> /dev/null 2>&1
```

at the end (after the command) so the cron won't spam you with outputs :)

Comment: how will it spam me with outputs? thanks.

Comment: The output of cron jobs goes to the mail box of the user it was running as by default.  If you haven't configured your mail server or added something to `/etc/aliases`, these will end up in `/var/spool/mail/<username>`.  Eventually, they will fill your filesystem... which is bad.

Comment: Exactly :) It is very interesting when you create a 1 or 2 minute crons and you open your mailbox after 2 days :)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, It currently has 280 lines. Thank you!

Comment: Only put that on the end of the line *after* you have tested it to ensure it's working correctly, otherwise it won't tell you if there is a problem.

Comment: +1 for the warning of spam!

Comment: What if it's not on `/var/spool/mail/<uname>`? Where else could it be located.

Answer (score 4):

The crontabs in `/etc/cron.d/` require a username in the 6th field, as does `/etc/crontab`.  User-based crontabs in `/var/spool/crontabs/` and via `crontab -e` do not have a username field.

Halfgaar's answer about the timing of the one that runs every 10 minutes is also correct.

Currently, these cron jobs execute `/var/www/site1/helper` as the `php` user rather than executing `/usr/bin/php` and passing it the arguments `/var/www/site1/helper post:make`.  This *will* work if your have a `php` user, the file is executable and has an appropriate shebang. (i.e `#!/usr/bin/php` as the first line.)  Otherwise, it will log an error in `/var/log/cron/log`.

The example below runs them as the `httpd` user and has an explicit path to the PHP executable.  You should choose an appropriate user.

```
0     0 * * *  httpd /usr/bin/php /var/www/site1/helper post:make
*/10  * * * *  httpd /usr/bin/php /var/www/site1/helper post:update
```

Comment: can I run it as a root user instead? Oh and Yeah I checked `var/log/cron` and it has a line about invalid username.

Comment: You certainly *can*.  Choosing a different user is part of the *principle of least privilege*.  If it doesn't *require* root, don't use root.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
10 * * * * php /var/www/site1/helper post:update
```

Will not run every 10 minutes, it will run at minute 10 of every hour (00:10, 01:10, ...).

This will run every 10 minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * php /var/www/site1/helper post:update
```